# link GetOpt to main jar

Tags: java, classpath

I have a folder `gnu\getopt` contains `Getopt.class` which is need by ChatDemo.jar for parser argument parameters, when I ran with `java -cp xSocket.jar;. ChatDemo.jar` it produce:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/getopt/Getopt
        at ChatDemo.main(ChatDemo.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.getopt.Getopt
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 1 more
```

ChatDemo.java:

```
import gnu.getopt.Getopt;
```

ChatDemo Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: ChatDemo
Class-Path: xSocket.jar
```

Comment: `gnu\getopt` is it under your jar or its outside?

Comment: It is outside, would be ideal if I can pack inside.

Comment: your Question seems not clear to me, which class you re tyring to execute ? where is it ? which jar is dependency

Comment: I have found the solution. If you have a better trick other than the one below. Feel free to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with `java -classpath "xSocket.jar;.;ChatDemo.jar ChatDemo` (no `.jar` after the name of the main class).

Note that you must add the folder which contains "gnu" to the classpath. Another solution is to put the getopt classes in a JAR and add that to the classpath. Make sure that the folder structure (`gnu\getopt`) is preserved.

Comment: No! As I said: Add the folder which **contains** the gnu folder to your classpath. If you start your app like this, you can ignore the class-path entry in the manifest. Otherwise add "." to the class-path entry. If you add "gnu", then Java will look for `gnu\gnu\getopt\...`!

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I assure this work without the " before xSocket.jar. I bet this is the most difficult argument ever in Java.

Comment: @Aaron - lots of people think that, but I've yet to see a proposal for a better alternative ...

Comment: @Stephen C: A good start would be to allow to mix `-cp` and `-jar` (that would allow to load JDBC drivers without having to remember a complex main classname). Next, it would be nice if `java` was more helpful. I'm missing options like "list all main() methods", command line option parsing so it can display a nice help for your main method, etc.

Comment: Yes ... well processing of arguments for / by the application could certainly be improved, but a lot of the problems are to do with the primitive interactions with the (external) command shell.  (If you are interested, take a look at what we did in JNode.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing up the two ways of running `java`.  You should either supply a classpath (e.g. using the `-cp` argument), or launch from a JAR file.  You cannot do both.

If you launch using a JAR file, the `-cp` argument is ignored.  In that case, you must specify the complete classpath in the JAR file's manifest.

The manifest in the ChatDemo.jar file apparently doesn't include.  You can remedy this in two ways:

- Update the manifest classpath to be "`Class-path: xSocket.jar .`" ... note we use a space to separate the entries here, not `;` or `:`.
- Add `Getopt.class` to the JAR file as `gnu/getopt/Getopt.class`.

However, if you launch using a JAR file you *have to* use the `-jar` option.  If you try to your application like this:

```
    java -cp xSocket.jar;. ChatDemo.jar
```

it will fail telling you that it cannot find a class called `ChatDemo.jar` ; i.e. it will misinterpret the JAR filename as a qualified classname.

Comment: so add gnu/getopt/Getopt.class to the class-path as in xSocket.jar;gnu/getopt/Getopt.class  is it correct?

Comment: See my updated answer.  (The JAR file manifest spec does not explicitly say how you put non-JARed classes / directories into the Class-path, but I've seen forum postings that say that this is the way to do it.)

Answer (score 1):

Add Main-Class - as fully qualified (I mean as per package structure) class name of your class which contains main method.